# Cordova android splash screen is not showing(showing black window) when you open all recent apps

Tags: android, cordova, background, splash-screen

Cordova android splash screen is not showing(showing black window) when you open all recent apps:

When opening the app splash screen is shown, but when you open recent apps a black window/background is shown instead of splash screen

```
<platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
        <icon density="ldpi" src="res/icon/android/drawable-ldpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="mdpi" src="res/icon/android/drawable-mdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="hdpi" src="res/icon/android/drawable-hdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xhdpi" src="res/icon/android/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xxhdpi" src="res/icon/android/drawable-xxhdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xxxhdpi" src="res/icon/android/drawable-xxxhdpi-icon.png" />
        <splash density="port-ldpi" src="res/screen/android/drawable-port-ldpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-mdpi" src="res/screen/android/drawable-port-mdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-hdpi" src="res/screen/android/drawable-port-hdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xhdpi" src="res/screen/android/drawable-port-xhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xxhdpi" src="res/screen/android/drawable-port-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xxxhdpi" src="res/screen/android/drawable-port-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
    </platform>
```